# How to validate use entered phone number using slots in botpress?

Tags: botpress

I am experimenting on botpress slots . There is the new option called as slot which will validate the user input . However I am not able to find resources which will validate the user input.

The bot must validate the use input as a phone number using slot feature or any other without use of external api ?

Is this possible ?

for example:

If the user inputs a valide phone number the flow will proceed.
else if use enters invalid phone number the flow will ask to re enter a valid phone number.

I have tried multiple things but had no luck finding the proper documentation/ tutorial regarding it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use a custom action to achieve this. A custom action for validating mobile number may look like:

```js
  const baseMessage = {
    type: 'text',
    markdown: false
  }

  /**
   * check if phone number is valid
   * @title validate phone number
   * @category Validation
   * @author Your name
   * @param {string} phone - phone number
   */
  const validateNumber = async phone => {
    var phoneRegex = /^\d{10}$/
    if (phone.match(phoneRegex)) {
      temp.phone_validation = 'success'
    } else {
      temp.phone_validation = 'error'
    }
  }

  return validateNumber(args.phone)
```

You can call the custom action in your validation flow and redirect user accordingly